# Filter network devices from pcap_findalldevs()

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pcap

I am supposed to sniff on all network interfaces installed on fiven machine (Linux - Ubuntu). I am using pcap library for this purpose. So I am finding all capable devices using pcap_findalldevs(...) function, but the result are also usb and loopback devices, which I dont want to use.

Can you sugegst me, how to filter only network (ethernet and wifi) devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it depends what you mean by “network” devices.

If you mean IPv4/IPv6 devices, you can interrogate the `pcap_if_t->address` returned by `pcap_findalldevs` and look at each address's `addr.sa_family` field to determine if that device supports `AF_INET` and/or `AF_INET6`. The loopback devices will `(pcap_if_t->flags & PCAP_IF_LOOPBACK) != 0`.

The problem with that is that will include devices which are not Ethernet and WiFi, like Token Ring, IP-over-Firewire, PPP, and such. PCAP doesn't provide a portable way to know the hardware type.

Answer (score 0):

If by "all network interfaces" you mean "all interfaces that are connected to physical networks and aren't capturing on things not thought of a networks" - the loopback interface is an example of the former and the USB capture devices on Linux and FreeBSD 9.0 and later are examples of the latter - then:

- you can eliminate loopback devices in the way apmasell's answer suggests;
- you can eliminate USB capture devices by ignoring interfaces for which `pcap_datalink()` returns `DLT_USB_LINUX` or `DLT_USB_LINUX_MMAPPED`;
- you can eliminate Bluetooth capture devices by ignoring interfaces for which `pcap_datalink()` returns `DLT_BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4` or `DLT_BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4_WITH_PHDR`.

You would need to open the devices to call `pcap_datalink()`.

That would probably eliminate most of the uninteresting devices (if you have Token Ring, PPP, etc. interfaces, you probably *do* want to capture on them).